How to edit the non-deductible portion of a donation that has been changed from non-deductible Financial Type to a deductible Financial Type?
I have some contributions that were incorrectly assigned to a "non-deductible" Financial Type. I have assigned one of them to the correct "deductible" Financial Type. When I save the changes, the contribution is updated with the new Financial Type, but I get the following message:

Non-deductible amount
You've changed the financial type for this $500.00 contribution from non-tax deductible to tax deductible, but the non-deductible amount of $500.00 has not been changed. This could prevent a tax receipt from being issued correctly. You may want to edit the non-deductible amount. [emphasis added]

But unfortunately the "Non-deductible Amount" in the "Additional Details" section of the edit dialog is not editable:

So how can this be edited? In this case, the entire $500 amount should be "deductible."
I'd like to be able to do this via the UI, but I could also use a solution using either API calls or a SQL update. Thanks!
This is Civi v.5.63.3 in WordPress v.6.1.1.

Wondering whether the Line Item Editor extension might be a UI solution? https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/lineitemedit/-/blob/master/README.md

Yes, exactly, it's the line items you'd need to edit. The financial type of the contribution as a whole is a legacy concept that doesn't do much, especially in terms of tax deductibility.
The line item editor extension is probably exactly what you want.
Of course, you may discover new issues when you try it, since the bookkeeping stuff in CiviCRM is full of surprises!
